# Django factoryboy fail when used as default parameter value

Tags: python, django, optional-parameters, factory-boy

I have a set of factories that I run during the test stage through a convenient function called `Create`. When I need to reference an existing project, I pass it as parameters, if not I create a new one with FactoryBoy:

```
def Create(project=ProjectFactory()):
    # do stuff with project
```

I am calling the function like so:

```
Create() # new project will be defined
Create(existing_project) # existing project will be used
```

But it doesn't work, I have a bunch of errors:

```
E   ProgrammingError: relation "auth_user" does not exist
E   LINE 1: ...user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user...
E                                                                 ^
```

After trying for some days different workarounds, I found that this version works:

```
def Create(project=None):
    project = ProjectFactory() if not project else project
    # do stuff with project
```

For me it does the same thing, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the default argument in `def Create(project=ProjectFactory()):` is bound at module loading time, essentially when the test runner starts. Since the test runner migrates the test database from scratch, it cannot create and save a `Project` at that point.

In the second version

```
def Create(project=None):
    project = ProjectFactory() if not project else project
```

The code that creates the `Project` is inside the function and is, thus, only executed once the function is called -- **after** the migrations ran.

Comment: If I understand correctly: the default parameter's value is loaded when the module load and not when the function is executed ?

Comment: Neat, do you have a reference/reading about this subject? I was really unaware of this loading difference.

Comment: Some discussion is here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/157373/python-mutable-default-argument-why and here: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/